# image receiving at android with no content- socket programming

Tags: java, android, sockets

i've created an application which send image from server (desktop) to client (android) via socket programming............the problem is i'm getting the file at the client side (android), but with no content.

can anyone please tell me what's the problem

**Client side (Android)**

```
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    receiveFile(dis); // call method receiveFile()

public Bitmap receiveFile(InputStream is) throws Exception{
                 String baseDir =     Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
                    String fileName = "myFile.png";
                    String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
                    System.out.println("FILE----------------->"+imageInSD);
                  int filesize=6022386;
                  int bytesRead;
                  int current = 0;
                  byte [] data  = new byte [filesize];

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = is.read(data,0,data.length);
                    current = bytesRead;
                    int index = 0;
                    while (index < filesize)
                    {
                        bytesRead = is.read(data, index, filesize - index);
                        if (bytesRead < 0)
                        {
                            throw new IOException("Insufficient data in stream");
                        }
                        index += filesize;
                    }

                    bos.write(data, 0 , current);  
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    return null;
              }
```

**Server (Desktop)**

```
send(socket.getOutputStream()); // call method send()


    public void send(OutputStream os) throws Exception{
      // sendfile
      File myFile = new File ("C:/div.png");
      System.out.println("the file is read");
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()+1];
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      System.out.println("Sending...");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      }
```

Comment: just scrolling through, but you read in line `is.read(data,0,data.length)`, but do not use the number of bytes read in there (shouldn't that go into `index`)?

Comment: The problem might be in the `index +=filesize;` it should be `index +=bytesread;` And also consider the previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to copy a stream in Java is as follows:

```
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
   out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

At present your code:

1. Assumes `read()` fills the buffer. There is nothing in the Javadoc that says so.
2. Ignores the result returned by `read()`, which in addition to being the invaluable count, could also be -1 indicating EOS.
3. Wastefully allocates a buffer the entire size of the file.
4. Assumes the size of the file fits into an `int`.
5. Relies on the receiver magically knowing the size of the incoming file.

The code above makes none of these assumptions, and works with any buffer size from 1 upwards.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code, I see you want to receive a file save it to the external storage and return the Bitmap of that file. That's what I guess you want to do but your code, as it is, does not do that. If you want you can use the following code to accomplish that task. First the server sends 4 bytes indicating the file's size followed by the file's contents; the client read that 4 bytes and then reads the whole file saving it to disk every chunk it reads. Finally, it converts the received file to a bitmap and returns it.

The client code:

```
public Bitmap receiveFile(InputStream is) throws Exception
    {
        String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = "myFile.png";
        String imageInSD = baseDir + File.separator + fileName;
        System.out.println("FILE----------------->" + imageInSD);

        // read first 4 bytes containing the file size
        byte[] bSize = new byte[4];
        is.read(bSize, 0, 4);

        int filesize;
        filesize = (int) (bSize[0] & 0xff) << 24 | 
                   (int) (bSize[1] & 0xff) << 16 | 
                   (int) (bSize[2] & 0xff) << 8 | 
                   (int) (bSize[3] & 0xff);

        int bytesRead;
        // You may but don't have to read the whole file in memory
        // 8k buffer is good enough
        byte[] data = new byte[8 * 1024];
        int bToRead;
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(imageInSD);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        while (filesize > 0)
        {
            // EDIT: just in case there is more data in the stream. 
            if (filesize > data.length) bToRead=data.length;
            else bToRead=filesize;
            bytesRead = is.read(data, 0, bToRead);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                bos.write(data, 0, bytesRead);
                filesize -= bytesRead;
            }
        }
        bos.close();
        // I guess you want to return the received image as a Bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(imageInSD);
        try
        {
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // in case of an error set it to null
            bmp = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            fis.close();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

The server code:

```
public void send(OutputStream os) throws Exception
{
    // sendfile
    File myFile = new File("C:/div.png");
    System.out.println("the file is read");
    int fSize = (int) myFile.length();
    byte[] bSize = new byte[4];
    bSize[0] = (byte) ((fSize & 0xff000000) >> 24);
    bSize[1] = (byte) ((fSize & 0x00ff0000) >> 16);
    bSize[2] = (byte) ((fSize & 0x0000ff00) >> 8);
    bSize[3] = (byte) (fSize & 0x000000ff);

    // send 4 bytes containing the filesize
    os.write(bSize, 0, 4);

    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) fSize];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    int bRead = bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
    System.out.println("Sending...");
    os.write(mybytearray, 0, bRead);
    os.flush();
    bis.close();
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. You need to constrain the read length so you never read past `filesize`. Also all that bit shifting should use `DataOutputStream.writeLong()` and `DataInputStream.readLong().`